# does it make any difference if particle of different materials are travelling at same wavelength and amplitude

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, waves, photons, wavelength

Will the wave still be called (radio wave or uv) as per its wavelength or frequency and not depending upon the type of particle.

Answer (score 2):

A radio wave and an ultraviolet wave always refer to electromagnetic waves. These terms are not used for matter waves.